# How to tell if an async computation is sent to the thread pool?

Tags: asynchronous, f#, threadpool

I was recently informed that in

```
async {
    return! async { return "hi" } }
|> Async.RunSynchronously
|> printfn "%s"
```

the nested `Async<'T>` (`async { return 1 }`) would not be sent to the thread pool for evaluation, whereas in

```
async {
    use ms = new MemoryStream [| 0x68uy; 0x69uy |]
    use sr = new StreamReader (ms)
    return! sr.ReadToEndAsync () |> Async.AwaitTask }
|> Async.RunSynchronously
|> printfn "%s"
```

the nested `Async<'T>` (`sr.ReadToEndAsync () |> Async.AwaitTask`) would be. What is it about an `Async<'T>` that decides whether it's sent to the thread pool when it's executed in an asynchronous operation like `let!` or `return!`? In particular, how would you define one which is sent to the thread pool? What code do you have to include in the `async` block, or in the lambda passed into `Async.FromContinuations`?

Comment: `ReadToEndAsync ()` queues an IO task on the Task pool. `Async` is just capturing the continuation of that.

Comment: @Asti Thanks. How does `ReadToEndAsync` do that? Is there a class which has methods like `QueueIOTaskOnTaskPool`?

Answer (score 5):

TL;DR: It's not quite like that. The `async` itself doesn't "send" anything to the thread pool. All it does is just run continuations until they stop. And if one of those continuations decides to continue on a new thread - well, that's when thread switching happens.

---

Let's set up a small example to illustrate what happens:

```
let log str = printfn $"{str}: thread = {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}"

let f = async {
  log "1"
  let! x = async { log "2"; return 42 }
  log "3"
  do! Async.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3.0))
  log "4"
}

log "starting"
f |> Async.StartImmediate
log "started"
Console.ReadLine()
```

If you run this script, it will print, `starting`, then `1`, `2`, `3`, then `started`, then wait 3 seconds, and then print `4`, and all of them except `4` will have the same thread ID. You can see that everything until `Async.Sleep` is executed synchronously on the same thread, but after that `async` execution stops and the main program execution continues, printing `started` and then blocking on `ReadLine`. By the time `Async.Sleep` wakes up and wants to continue execution, the original thread is already blocked on `ReadLine`, so the async computation gets to continue running on a new one.

What's going on here? How does this function?

**First**, the way the async computation is structured is in ["continuation-passing style"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style). It's a technique where every function doesn't return its result to the caller, but calls another function instead, passing the result as its parameter.

Let me illustrate with an example:

```
// "Normal" style:
let f x = x + 5
let g x = x * 2
printfn "%d" (f (g 3)) // prints 11

// Continuation-passing style:
let f x next = next (x + 5)
let g x next = next (x * 2)
g 3 (fun res1 -> f res1 (fun res2 -> printfn "%d" res2))
```

This is called "continuation-passing" because the `next` parameters are called "continuations" - i.e. they're functions that express how the program *continues* after calling `f` or `g`. And yes, this is exactly what `Async.FromContinuations` means.

Seeming very silly and roundabout on the surface, what this allows us to do is for each function to decide when, how, or even *if* its continuation happens. For example, our `f` function from above could be doing something asynchronous instead of just plain returning the result:

```
let f x next = httpPost "http://calculator.com/add5" x next
```

Coding it in continuation-passing style would allow such function to *not block* the current thread while the request to `calculator.com` is in flight. What's wrong with blocking the thread, you ask? I'll refer you to [the original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66441686/180286) that prompted your question in the first place.

---

**Second**, when you write those `async { ... }` blocks, the compiler gives you a little help. It takes what looks like a step-by-step imperative program and "unrolls" it into a series of continuation-passing calls. The "breaking" points for this unfolding are all the constructs that end with a bang - `let!`, `do!`, `return!`.

The above `async` block, for example, would look somethiing like this (F#-ish pseudocode):

```
let return42 onDone = 
  log "2"
  onDone 42

let f onDone =
  log "1"
  return42 (fun x ->
    log "3"
    Async.Sleep (3 seconds) (fun () ->
      log "4"
      onDone ()
    )
  )
```

Here, you can plainly see that the `return42` function simply calls its continuation right away, thus making the whole thing from `log "1"` to `log "3"` completely synchronous, whereas the `Async.Sleep` function doesn't call its continuation right away, instead scheduling it to be run later (in 3 seconds) on the thread pool. That's where the thread switching happens.

And here, finally, lies the answer to your question: in order to have the `async` computation jump threads, your callback passed to `Async.FromContinuations` should do anything but call the success continuation immediately.

---

**A few notes for further investigation**

1. The `onDone` technique in the above example is technically called ["monadic bind"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)#Definition), and indeed in real F# programs it's represented by the `async.Bind` method. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64994978/180286) might also be of help understanding the concept.
2. The above is a bit of an oversimplification. [In reality](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/main/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/async.fs) the `async` execution is a bit more complicated than that. Internally it uses a technique called ["trampoline"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trampoline_(computing)), which in plain terms is just a loop that runs a single thunk on every turn, but crucially, the running thunk can also "ask" it to run another thunk, and if it does, the loop will do so, and so on, forever, until the next thunk doesn't ask to run another thunk, and then the whole thing finally stops.
3. I specifically used `Async.StartImmediate` to start the computation in my example, because `Async.StartImmediate` will do just what it says on the tin: it will start running the computation immediately, right there. That's why everything ran on the same thread as the main program. There are [many alternative starting functions in the `Async` module](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-control-fsharpasync.html). For example, `Async.Start` will start the computation on the thread pool. The lines from `log "1"` to `log "3"` will still all happen synchronously, without thread switching between them, but it will happen on a different thread from `log "start"` and `log "starting"`. In this case thread switching will happen before the `async` computation even starts, so it doesn't count.

Comment: Where is the code that makes the thread switching happen? In `Async.Sleep`? In `AsyncBuilder`?

Comment: As I explained in the answer: "... _Async.Sleep function doesn't call its continuation right away, instead scheduling it to be run later_ ..." [Here's the precise line](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/3815b8f5d1a0089898428281d2139b0e6f5cd7ed/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/async.fs#L1383) if you insist.